# Converting numeric list in python to text based list

Tags: python

How can I convert a python list like:

```
[0, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 , 4/4]
```

into the following:

```
[r'$25^{th}$', r'$50^{th}$', r'$75^{th}$', r'$100^{th}$']
```

Here each element of the 2nd list corresponds to a percentile value E.g. in the first list the element 0 corresponds to values below the 25th percentile. I want the solution to be easily extendible to different lengths e.g. current list has 5 elements, but we could have 2 elements or 10. Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: post your attempts.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html#scipy.stats.percentileofscore

Comment: what are your percentile marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this I guess:

```
a = [0, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 , 4/4]
b = [r'$%i^{th}$' % (i*100) for i in a[1:]] #skips first value
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists have a function called list.extend(seq) which can dynamically extend your list with a sequence. For example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
l.extend([5,6])
print(l) # [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Now, to answer your actual question:

```
perclist = ["%4.2f th" % (float(i)*100) for i in fraclist]
```

Comment: @ofer I thought of keeping it simple without using list comprehension but I guess this is more pythonic. Thanks for typing it out.